# Java, Adding time LinkedList vs ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures

just adding Integer numbers to Arraylist and Linkedlist, to the last position, why adding in arrayList is faster then the linkedlist? I compiled many many times, and adding in arraylist is faster, why?

As I know, ArrayList copies an array by 2^n+1 size. while linkedlist changes only the Node

```
class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

    addToList(arrayList);
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    addToList(linkedList);

}

public static void addToList(List list) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5_000_000; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

}

}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java). P.S.: Could be about the amount of memory required for the operations.

Comment: Plus the usual caveat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441079/java-performance-measurement Add to `linkedList` first and see how the result differs.

Comment: I have seen that post, and there was said that adding in last position is O(1) for both arraylist and linkedlist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is LinkedList really faster than ArrayList in the case of insertion in the middle of list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808777/is-linkedlist-really-faster-than-arraylist-in-the-case-of-insertion-in-the-middl)

Comment: @Tom the question is not about the middle of the list...

Comment: My link uses "insertion in the middle", but the general information regarding LL vs AL in the answers are still good.

Comment: That post is not correct. `LinkedList.add()` is *O(N)* unless done with a list iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add to an `ArrayList`, you just have to store the integer in the backing array. Every once in a while, when the backing array fills up, you have to allocate a new array and copy all the old items to the new array. Given 5 million integers, you'll have to do that allocate-and-copy about 20 times (depends on the initial size of the list).

To add to a linked list, every addition requires that you:

1. Allocate memory for and initialize a new linked list node.
2. Link the new node to the end of the list.

All that extra work, for both the `ArrayList` and the `LinkedList` is done behind the scenes, by the `add` method.

The overhead for 5 million linked list node allocations and links is higher than the overhead for 5 million `ArrayList` insertions, even when you count the 20 or so allocate-and-copy operations that the `ArrayList` has to make when it fills up.

So, whereas each operation takes constant time (although in the `ArrayList` case it's really *amortized* constant time), the constant for appending to a linked list is higher than the constant for appending to an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` does not copy the whole array every time, it creates a new array doubled in size every time there is no more space in the current array.

So if you have an `ArrayList` with 3 elements, the size of the underlying array is probably 4. Therefore, adding a new element does not require creating a new array and copying the 3 values, and thus has time complexity of O(1).

They are both O(1) now, but `ArrayList` only needs to put the value in the correct place in memory, whereas `LinkedList` needs to allocate new space (for the new node).

Comment: arraylist size with 3 elements is 3,not 4