# Why does java.util.Stack not use a composite pattern with LinkedList, instead of Vektor?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to understand this:

In java, Stack extends Vector. That's OK. It's a **synchronized** implementation. However, synchronization isn't always needed, in such cases, **it's advised to use ArrayDeque.**

***But If Stack would have been built using composite pattern with LinkedList, wouldn't it have been better?*** LinkedList provides better performance for inserting and deleting. Additionally, arrays are fixed in size, anytime you need to increase the size of the list, you also need to reallocate a new array and copy the contents over. **Finally, with LinkedList an implementation for Stack may be easier and more performant than array.**

```
public class ListStack implements Stack {

private final List _list = new LinkedList();

public void push(Object value) {
    _list.add(value);
}

public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    return _list.delete(_list.size() - 1);
}

public Object peek() throws EmptyStackException {
    Object result = pop();
    push(result);
    return result;
}


public void clear() {
     _list.clear();
}

public int size() {
    return _list.size();
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return _list.isEmpty();
}

public void enqueue(Object value) {
      push(value);
}

public Object dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException {
    try {
        return pop();
    }catch (EmptyStackException ex) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's no need for such a wrapper, as `LinkedList` implements [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), just as `ArrayDeque`. Thus, usage is not bound to either class.

Comment: performant ... depends on the use case, linked list is faster for insert/delete, but slower for get, here's a [small study](https://dzone.com/articles/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311008/java-adding-time-linkedlist-vs-arraylist/58311267#58311267

Answer (score 2):

This:

> LinkedList provides better performance for inserting and deleting.

And this:

> Finally, with LinkedList an implementation for Stack may be easier and more performant than array

are incorrect.

They're still incorrect even when you consider this:

> Additionally, arrays are fixed in size, anytime you need to increase the size of the list, you also need to reallocate a new array and copy the contents over.

Stack is based on `Vector`, because it's more efficient than a linked list in terms of both speed and memory consumption.

Lets say you push 1 million items onto the end of the list/top of the stack.

How many memory allocations are performed all together?  Vector: ~20.  LinkedList: ~1000000

How many bytes are modified (pretty much proportional to remaining time taken)? Vector: ~10MB.  LinkedList: ~24MB

Total memory consumption?  Vector: ~4MB, LinkedList: ~16MB

Comment: Note for pedants:  memory numbers assume a 64-bit VM with compressed oops (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop) or a 32-bit VM

Comment: Note for pedants: The memory consumption is of course the list's overhead. If each item requires 1 KB by itself, the total memory consumption is 1 GB (items) + 4~16 MB (list structure). Also note that a re-allocation on a large array-based list is more likely to exceed the JVM's heap space than a new allocation on a linked-based list.