# Difference between Collections.sort() and getting a sorted collection by adding into a TreeSet?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections

```
 Set<Student> ts = new TreeSet<Student>();

    for(Student s : studentInfo){
         ts.add(s);
    }

    System.out.println(ts);
```

I've written this above snippet in one of my case block in order to sort a collection of Student Objects. 
My question is: What is the difference between using this approach and using `Collections.sort();` method.

Comment: Collection.sort() , can be optimised with a comparator method , which will sort the collection object according to the attribute you define , you can chose any attribute to be the decider one and create a comparing class defining the comparing method with that attribute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is that a `TreeSet` keeps you data sorted at all times while the `Collections.sort()` method sorts it when you call the method on your `Set`.

The time complexity of `Collections.sort()` is `O(n*log(n))` while the `TreeSet`'s `add()`'s complexity is `log(n)`. If you use the same size of data then the complexity in the `TreeSet`'s case will be the same because you repeat the `add` operation `n` times.

So you only have to decide whether you want your `Set` ordered at all times or just at some point. If there is a case in your code when you don't need sorting then you don't need `TreeSet` but if you will always need it to be sorted then you should use `TreeSet`.

**Please keep in mind** that if you want to sort your `Set` you have to create a `List` from it first which might introduce some overhead!

**Another caveat:** As others mentioned `TreeSet` can only take 1 `Comparator` while you can supply different `Comparator`s to `Collections.sort()`. So it **depends on your usage**. You should give us more information on your use case in order to give you a thorough answer.

Comment: I was editing my answer when your comment arrived. It is in there now.

Comment: There are other cases in my code where i have add/search/display functionality.

Comment: @AdamArold I have created studentInfo is a `LinkedList`, to which i add the Student objects in the first case. I've used the `TreeSet` to sort the same collection in a second case block.

Comment: You should just use `Collections.sort()` then.

Comment: BTW A set will drop duplicates (as defined by the comparator), whereas a List allows any number of duplicates.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj An ArrayList is likely to be a better choice if you want to sort it. In most cases ArrayList is preferable to LinkedList.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I had asked a question regarding that just yesterday. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734705/which-one-runs-faster-arraylist-or-linkedlist

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj ArrayList has a higher worst case add time but is many times faster on average. It also uses far less memory (as little as 1/4)  Its references are continuous in memory making random but also sequential access more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

1) A **TreeSet** like all **Set** refuses duplicate values.

2) A **TreeSet** maintains the sort every time you insert elements while a list sorted with **Collections.sort()** will only be sorted after the call to sort() (and will not maintain this sort upon add()).

3) **Collections.sort()** allows to sort the list on differents criterias using different **Comparators**. With a TreeSet, you can also give a Comparator but you will need to instantiate one TreeSet for each Comparator.

Comment: Point 3) is not necessary since you can supply a `Comparator` to the `TreeMap` as well.

Comment: I meant that with Sets, you need to instantiate a TreeSet for each Comparator whereas Collections.sort() allows to sort the same list with different Comparators.

Comment: @AdamArold Did you mean `TreeSet`?

Comment: Yes. Internally `TreeSet` uses a `Map` by the way.