# Measuring time does not confirm LinkedList advantage

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, listiterator

I am reading the differrences between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` pointed out in [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist). I developed a small example applcation to test a major advantage of `LinkedList` but the results I obtain do not confirm, that `LinkedList` outweighs `ArrayList` in the performance of the operation:

```
ListIterator.add(E element)
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 100000;

        long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fillLinkedList(number);
        long stopTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fillArrayList(number);
        long stopTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(" LinkedList needed: "+ (stopTime1 - startTime1));
        System.out.println(" ArrayList needed: "+ (stopTime2 - startTime2));

    }


    public static void fillLinkedList(int number){

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(i++<number){
            it.add(i);
        }
    //  System.out.println("LinkedList size: "+list.size());

    }


    public static void fillArrayList(int number){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(i++<number){
            it.add(i);
        }
    //  System.out.println("ArrayList size: "+list.size());
    }
```

The measurement gives:

```
number            10,000     100,000     500,000      1,000,000     5,000,000

ArrayList            7         17         60             77           170

LinkedList           7         21         89             838          4127
```

I notice that the increase of elements impairs significantly the performance of `LinkedList` while `ArrayList` presents a considerably better behaviour. Have I understood something false?

Comment: Note that with `LinkedList` you need to create a `Node` object for every insertion. With `ArrayList` you have to grow the array.

Comment: You understood everything right. Stack Overflow is full of s...

Comment: For future measurements, you should probably use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the precision is much much less for the latter and you're not actually measuring the current time here but a difference between 2 points.

Comment: If you populate ArrayList first and LinkedList later, then the results are very different. ArrayList still wins mostly, but it is a lot closer.

Comment: Oh, and please post complete executable samples, whenever possible, it makes investigation easier.

Comment: Why do you think `LinkedList` should be faster than `ArrayList` in this case? I can see nothing in the referenced question tht supports this assumption. `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` have the same asymptotic amortized behavior for appending. However, the constant factor is significant smaller for the latter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656471/performance-differences-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist

Comment: Ok, the answer of the linked question writes ListIterator.add(E element) is O(n-index) in ArrayList. I do not understand what is index when looping over the list with an iterator. Based on its best case though, the performace should be at least equal, what can be proved by my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ArrayList` is faster when adding element at the end of container or very close, since it doesn't need to shift many elements then. It is slow, when adding in the middle or at the beginning. I changed your loop into the following:

```
    while(i++<number){
        it.add(i);
        if(i%2 == 0)
            it.previous();
    }
```

Now, `it` will always point to the middle of `list`. With this benchmark, `LinkedList` is much faster. Results for 200000:

```
LinkedList needed: 47
ArrayList needed: 4702
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by: "Now, it will always point to the middle of list"? I do not think your code does that.

Comment: @arjacsoh - every second `add` I go back one element. In effect I do `add` n times, but move forward only n/2 times.

Comment: That is true but not the same with your claim "Now, it will always point to the middle of list".

Comment: @arjacsoh, if you want me to be extremely precise: after each iteration of the loop `it` will point to element with index `(list.size()+1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion and deletion at the beginning or middle (of the array or list) is where a list beats out an array.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, the benefit of a LinkedList is on insertion of a value into a given index (say, the middle, or the start). ArrayList won't lose out on sequential insertion, as it doesn't have to shift elements over.

Once you have populated your lists as above, see what you get for in-position insertion to different places. I've modified your example to show an example of where LinkedList wins significantly (on my setup at least):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 5000000;

    LinkedList<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    fillLinkedList(number, llist);
    long stopTime1 = System.nanoTime();

    long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    fillArrayList(number, alist);
    long stopTime2 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(" LinkedList needed: "+ (stopTime1 - startTime1));
    System.out.println(" ArrayList needed: "+ (stopTime2 - startTime2));

    startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    llist.add(1, 4);
    stopTime1 = System.nanoTime();

    startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    alist.add(1, 4);
    stopTime2 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(" LinkedList needed: "+ (stopTime1 - startTime1));
    System.out.println(" ArrayList needed: "+ (stopTime2 - startTime2));

}

public static void fillLinkedList(int number, LinkedList<Integer> list){


    ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
    int i = 0;
    while(i++<number){
        it.add(i);
    }
    //  System.out.println("LinkedList size: "+list.size());

}


public static void fillArrayList(int number, ArrayList<Integer> list){
    ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
    int i = 0;
    while(i++<number){
        it.add(i);
    }
    //  System.out.println("ArrayList size: "+list.size());
}
```