# Why is LinkedList so much slower than ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I saw many benchmark of ArrayList vs LinkedList on the Internet, but most of them perform insertion/deletion at the end of the list. So I tried make my own performance benchmark where insertion/deletion is at an arbitrary position in both lists. I found out that LinkedList is much slower in all basic operation such as access/search/insertion/deletion. Can someone please help explain to me why is this?

Here is an example output:

Time is in milliseconds

```
ArrayList: 
Access: 5
Search: 64917
Access: 2740
Access: 3529

LinkedList: 
Access: 56574
Search: 216184
Insertion: 101892
Deletion: 43008

HashMap: 
Access: 14
Search: 11
Insertion: 15
Deletion: 14

TreeMap: 
Access: 48
Search: 41
Insertion: 57
Deletion: 52

HashSet: 
Search: 13
Insertion: 18
Deletion: 17

TreeSet: 
Search: 40
Insertion: 41
Deletion: 33
```

TestRun.java

```
public class TestRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 100000;

        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arrayList.add(rand.nextInt(n));
            linkedList.add(rand.nextInt(n));
            hashSet.add(rand.nextInt(n));
            treeSet.add(rand.nextInt(n));
            hashMap.put(rand.nextInt(n), i);
            treeMap.put(rand.nextInt(n), i);
        }
        System.out.println("Time is in milliseconds \n");

        System.out.println("ArrayList: ");
        System.out.println("Access: " + ListRunTime.accessTime(arrayList, n));
        System.out.println("Search: " + ListRunTime.searchTime(arrayList, n));
        System.out.println("Access: " + ListRunTime.insertionTime(arrayList, n));
        System.out.println("Access: " + ListRunTime.deletionTime(arrayList, n));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("LinkedList: ");
        System.out.println("Access: " + ListRunTime.accessTime(linkedList, n));
        System.out.println("Search: " + ListRunTime.searchTime(linkedList, n));
        System.out.println("Insertion: " + ListRunTime.insertionTime(linkedList, n));
        System.out.println("Deletion: " + ListRunTime.deletionTime(linkedList, n));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("HashMap: ");
        System.out.println("Access: " + MapRunTime.accessTime(hashMap, n));
        System.out.println("Search: " + MapRunTime.searchTime(hashMap, n));
        System.out.println("Insertion: " + MapRunTime.insertionTime(hashMap, n));
        System.out.println("Deletion: " + MapRunTime.deletionTime(hashMap, n));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("TreeMap: ");
        System.out.println("Access: " + MapRunTime.accessTime(treeMap, n));
        System.out.println("Search: " + MapRunTime.searchTime(treeMap, n));
        System.out.println("Insertion: " + MapRunTime.insertionTime(treeMap, n));
        System.out.println("Deletion: " + MapRunTime.deletionTime(treeMap, n));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("HashSet: ");
        System.out.println("Search: " + SetRunTime.searchTime(hashSet, n));
        System.out.println("Insertion: " + SetRunTime.insertionTime(hashSet, n));
        System.out.println("Deletion: " + SetRunTime.deletionTime(hashSet, n));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("TreeSet: ");
        System.out.println("Search: " + SetRunTime.searchTime(treeSet, n));
        System.out.println("Insertion: " + SetRunTime.insertionTime(treeSet, n));
        System.out.println("Deletion: " + SetRunTime.deletionTime(treeSet, n));
    }

    // access: arraylist, linkedlist, hashtable, 
    // search: arraylist, linkedlist, hashtable, treeset
    // insertion: arraylist, linkedlist, hashtable, treeset
    // deletion: arraylist, linkedlist, hashtable, treeset

}
```

ListRunTime.java

```
public class ListRunTime {
    private static final Random RAND = new Random();

    public static long accessTime(List<Integer> list, int n) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.get(RAND.nextInt(n));
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);
    }

    public static long searchTime(List<Integer> list, int n) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.contains(RAND.nextInt(n));
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);
    }

    public static long insertionTime(List<Integer> list, int n) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(RAND.nextInt(n), i);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);
    }

    public static long deletionTime(List<Integer> list, int n) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.remove(RAND.nextInt(n - i));
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: `LinkedList` good for sequential access, `ArrayList` good for random access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656471/performance-differences-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist